# New to JavaScript, function doesn't seem to run (Notify.js)

Tags: javascript, php

this is probably very simple but I'm new to JavaScript and not really sure what I'm doing wrong.

Basically I have a profile configuration page on a website and through a form, you can change your nickname, email, preferred method of contact, etc. I was looking for ways to easily display a notification when you successfully change something and found notify.js - unfortunately, couldn't find much help on actually installing/using this besides how to call it's functions and nothing I try seems to work.

I copied the text from this page and put it in a local file called notify.js - it's in the same directory as the rest of the files.
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/msroot/Notify.js/master/Notify.js

I'm trying to call the Notify function to display the success/error message but it never seems to show up:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    ...code...
    <script src="notify.js"></script>
    <?php
      if ($nickChanged == 1) {
        ?>
          <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
              Notify("An error occurred while saving your new nickname.", null, null, 'danger');
            );
          </script>
        <?php
        } else if ($nickChanged == 2) {
        ?>
          <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
              Notify("Successfully changed nickname!", null, null, 'success');
            });
          </script>
        <?php
        }
      ?>
  </head>
```

Anyone have any idea as to what I'm doing wrong? Again, it's probably simple but this is basically my first time using JavaScript at all

Rendered HTML as per request:

```html
...code...
<script src="notify.js"></script>
                    <script>
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    Notify("Successfully changed nickname!", null, null, 'success');
                });
            </script>
                </head>
...code...
```

Found this error in the browser console:
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at http://*website*.net/sc/profile.php:80:17

In the actual php file, line 80 is CSS but in the rendered page, it's this line:
 $(document).ready(function() {

Someone mentioned I should add jQuery so I added this line:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Still not showing notifications, should that have fixed it?

Comment: Show the exactly rendered html, without any php.

Comment: And any errors or other suspicious output from the browser console and network tabs (F12)

Comment: Edited OP, thanks for responding!

Comment: Looks like you didn't include jQuery

Comment: What does your console say now you've added that line?

Comment: Console's empty. Progress!

Comment: Do you have a div with the id `notifications` as specified in the docs?

Comment: Did you include jQuery?

Comment: @PatrickQ - Just added that, didn't notice I had to before. Now it shows an unstyled notification in the top left. Basically just a tiny x then the text I specified right of that. Shouldn't it do the styling on itself since I used one of the defaults? (success and danger)

Comment: You're probably also not including bootstrap.

Comment: Hey! You found my mistake. Sorry for being a noob :p Thanks for all the help, guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add bootstrap and font awesome beside jQuery:

```
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cabin' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
```